# How do obtain the local minimum and maximum points of a stock using yfinance in python?

Tags: python, database, data-science, finance, stock

I'am trying to predict if a stock is a buying point or a selling point using logistical regressio. In order to do this, I require the local minimum and maximum points of a stock. For example,

[image]

Image from: https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/MRNA?showOptin=1

0: represents local minimum and 1: represents local maximum

How do I insert these values into a dataframe. For example if a stock was a local minimum point yesterday how would I use yfinance in python to put 0 in my dataframe. Basically what I'am asking is how do I obtain this specific point? Is it is shown as red or green in the graph. However how do I insert it as 1 or 0 in my dataframe using yfinance.

I couldn't find any info on how to obtain this data. I heard it was on TD ameritrade however it is not of my best interest to sign up for it. Furthermore, the local minimum and maximum points are shown as red or green on the yahoofinance charts online. However I would like these red and green points to be ones and zeros in my data frame. In addition, Yahoo finance does not provide the local maximum or minimum info on their spreadsheets of historical data aswell.

Comment: these are not local minima or maxima, this is trade volume you are looking at. to get the local minimum and maximia in a range you can map volume with date and then from there you can make analytics

Comment: @sahasrara62 may you further clarify what you said please?. I'am new to this whole stock market feild, sorry.

Comment: these red and green line are some indicator, probably volume per day/min/week the time frame you have decided. to get the local minima or maxima in a range you need to check the prices of these stock in that range and then from that calculate the things

Comment: but I want to know if it is a buying point or selling point each day for more information go to this site, this is what I'am trying to reverse engineer https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-im-using-machine-learning-to-trade-in-the-stock-market-3ba981a2ffc2

Answer (score 2):

I think you need do like this

```
df["local"] = df["price"] > df["price"].shift(1)
df["local"] = df["price"].fillna(True)
```

then in df["local"] , Ture means 1 and False means 0